# How to search a 2D array and return the elements

Tags: python, arrays

in my program i want the user to enter a number and that number to be searched and return the elements from the 2D array.

`for example if input = 1 then array[1][1,2,3,4,5,6] and separately array[1][7,8]`

```
player = [[2, 17, 19, 19, 21, 29, 8, 17],[9, 5, 17, 18, 23, 28, 2, 2],[5, 8, 18, 18, 29, 30, 25, 26],[5, 6, 15, 13, 23, 24, 12, 12]]
playerID = int(input("Please enter player ID "))
print(playerID)
for i in array(playerID):
   for j in array(6):
       print(array[i][j])
else:
   print("not found")
```

```
pseudocode

get playerID 
print playerID
search for playerID in player
    access the elements upto 6 
        print player[playerID] [player's Elements] 
else
    print not found
```

Comment: Is it a numpy array or a list or lists?

Comment: it not a numpy array,    it a 2D list

Answer (score 0):

```py
player = [[2, 17, 19, 19, 21, 29, 8, 17],[9, 5, 17, 18, 23, 28, 2, 2],[5, 8, 18, 18, 29, 30, 25, 26],[5, 6, 15, 13, 23, 24, 12, 12]]
playerID = int(input("Please enter player ID "))
for p in player:
    if playerID in p[:6]:
        print([playerID],p[:6])
        print([playerID],p[6:])
```

**Output**

```py
Please enter player ID 5
[5] [9, 5, 17, 18, 23, 28]
[5] [2, 2]
[5] [5, 8, 18, 18, 29, 30]
[5] [25, 26]
[5] [5, 6, 15, 13, 23, 24]
[5] [12, 12]
```

Comment: this prints all the element lists that has the number five. What I'm trying to achieve is for example `if input = 1 then array**[1][1,2,3,4,5,6]**` it should only return the elements of that list

Comment: Can you provide an expected outcome on  your `player` data `if input =5`?